# Overflow Errors in 64-bit Windows Server 2012 after Upgrade to .NET Framework?

Tags: .net, winapi, 64-bit, dllimport, windows-server-2012

Our solution was recently upgraded from .NET Framework v3.5 to v4.5.2 and as a result we have had some overflow errors running on Windows Server 2012 64-bit machines.

These overflow errors seem to be coming from any instance where we call this function from the Windows API:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

The overflow was happening because for lParam in some instances, for whatever reason, it was being passed an int instead of an IntPtr even though the function expects an IntPtr.

What was interesting was these issues only manifested after upgrading .NET and ONLY on Windows Server 2012 64-bit machines.

I'm trying to decipher the cause for this only happening under these circumstances, and also trying to find an effective way to find where other instances of this kind of overflow error could occur.

My first thought was to look for all instances where SendMessage was being called, but this could miss some other instances where IntPtr is being misused. My other idea was to use either ReSharper or FXCop to detect these sort of instances and alert me to them, but I don't know how or if this is possible and by default ReSharper isn't giving any complaints.

Comment: Hard to say. You didn't provide enough code. Nor an error message. We could try to guess what's going on, but really, what's the point? `wParam` should be `IntPtr`. Whether that's your problem, who can say.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Do you mean `lParam` or `wParam`? I did not know that `wParam` is expected to be a IntPtr too. In this case I don't think a code example would really help, it's just `SendMessage(Some IntPtr, Some int, Some int, Some int);` in the cases where it was causing overflows.

Comment: I meant exactly what I said. Both `wParam` and `lParam` are pointer sized. This much is well documented. If you don't want to provide more details, if you don't want to provide an error message, then I wish you luck in solving your problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the correct declaration for SendMessage and how do I convert my code to use its parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16269994/what-is-the-correct-declaration-for-sendmessage-and-how-do-i-convert-my-code-to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `IntPtr` instead of `int` because the last two arguments of the `SendMessage` function are pointers. See [Windows Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx) about `WPARAM` and `LPARAM` types.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

Comment: Marking this as the correct answer since the possible duplicate question you linked helped solve the problem. Thanks!