# P/Invokes running on Windows Server 2012 and Net Framework 4.5.2 suddenly generate >32bit pointers

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

Using C#, Windows Server 2012 R2 x64 and .NET framework 4.5.2.

I'm working on an older piece of software that has some bad P/Invoke calls that use ints where IntPtrs are needed. The calls have been in the system for years, running without issue under .NET 3.5. Some calls began failing on Server 2012 when we migrated to framework 4.5.2. They now return pointers way out in 64-bit space. No similar behavior is observed on Windows 7 (for example), and framework 4.0 on Server 2012 also doesn't do this.

I've fixed the calls - they're defects, of course - but it bothers me that I can't explain why a framework upgrade suddenly started generating pointers larger than 32-bits, on only one operating system. The behavior is regular and reproducible, both the failing behavior on Server 2012 and OK behavior elsewhere. I have assumed this is related to address space layout randomization (ASLR) - but that's been active since Server 2008, and there's nothing anywhere to suggest this has been modified or enabled. Does any one know more, or should I just write this off to the way things evolve over time and not think about it?

Note this is not a duplicate of [Overflow Errors in 64-bit Windows Server 2012 after Upgrade to .NET Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28880570/overflow-errors-in-64-bit-windows-server-2012-after-upgrade-to-net-framework) - I know why my errors are occurring, we had bad stuff going on. What I am curious about 
is what might have changed in the underlying framework to suddenly surface the problems.

Comment: It's very difficult to say, that's up to the Windows memory manager. We saw the exact same behavior in another library we were using; despite using `int` for addresses, it worked fine until we moved to the .NET Framework 4.5 from 3.5 SP1.

Comment: This is not unusual, the [Control Flow Guard](http://www.alex-ionescu.com/?p=246) feature enabled on Win8.1 Update 3 is an example.  Best way to find out what happened to Server 2012 is at serverfault.com perhaps.